# Menu bar movement from under banner to fix position on top of page?

Tags: css, menu, positioning, html

The title explains it. I can't seem to figure out the specific way to put it while searching for a way to have a menu bar under a banner, then, have it move up to a fixed position on the top of the page as you scroll down (kind of like the salmon-colored box that is currently showing up to the right of this form).

I will be using a simple table for a menu bar.

Many Thanks!
Sean

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Not yet.  I currently have my menu bar fixed to the top of my page from the pageload. It looks decent, but, i'm still curious about how to go about doing the above.

Comment: I'd recommend posting some code.